# Xcode 8 App Archive validation failed with errors

Tags: ios, validation, xcode8, itunes, archive

When I validate the app archive I receive this message:

> The operation couldn't be completed.  iTunesSoftwareAuthenticationErrorDomain error 434

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot of error?

Comment: @Arasuvel I added the link to screenshot

Comment: @Carlito did you try it a second time?

Comment: now it works , Thanks @Fabio Berger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without XCode:

1. Create archive in Xcode
2. Export IPA in Organiser (Xcode > window > Organiser)
3. Open Application Loader and manually choose IPA generated
4. Done

Solution with XCode:

1. Create archive in Xcode
2. Click Validate
3. Unselect BitCode
4. Check if its validated, mine got validated when i unchecked bitcode
5. Not Try to genrate similar fashion with Bitcode unselected
6. If all goes fine now generate with Bitcode Checked(mine worked with these exact steps)
7. Done